# No command sudo found on Debian server

Tags: debian, sudo, gitlab

I want to have GitLab under domain git.blue-world.pl. 
I use [Omnibus package downloads for GitLab CE](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/) for Debian 7.

1. `ssh -l login blue-world.pl`
2. `cd domains/git.blue-world.pl/public_html`
3. `wget https://downloads-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/debian-7.7/gitlab_7.6.1-omnibus.5.3.0.ci.1-1_amd64.deb`
4. but when I type `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` I receive that there is no command `sudo`.

What should I do?

Comment: Please ask questions about specific problems rather than very broad things where you would need a full tutorial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sudo` is not installed on Debian by default. You have to install it.

You don't need `sudo` to install software, but you need to become root instead:

```
su -
```

After that you can:

```
apt-get install openssh-server
```

Comment: i think, on my hosting there is no possible for me to login as a root.

Comment: Then you cannot install `openssh-server` on it. As a matter of fact it looks like it's already installed, how else could you `ssh` to it?

Comment: But do i install it in a good place? The second point is good?

Comment: You never installed it, you just downloaded it to a directory and didn't unpack it. When you install it, Debian will know where to put everything.

Comment: I also find it interesting that you don't have the root password, because if you installed it then you should have been asked to enter a password for root.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this method and it worked for me.

1. Log in then switch to superuser using `su`
2. Run the following command to install sudo

   `apt-get install sudo`
3. For **Debian 9** run `adduser <username> sudo` to add user to group sudo. Replace  with your account username
   If you dont know, just run `whoami` to get your account username
   For **Debian 10 or 11** run `/sbin/adduser username sudo`

Logout and login with the same user then try running

```
sudo echo 'Hello, world!'
```

The terminal should return `Hello, world!`